# Scheme function that returns longer list of the two inputs

Tags: scheme

I want to write a function that takes two list arguments and returns the longer list of the two inputs. If the two lists are equal in length, the function returns #t, and if one of the arguments is not a list, the function should return #f.

Sample runs:

- (longer-list '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d e)) returns (a b c d e)
- (longer-list '(d e f) '(4 5 6)) returns #t (or true)
- (longer-list '(g    h i) 3) returns #f (or false)
  How can I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially a specification asking for code, with no attempt at solving the problem shown, and with no particular problem in programming described.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you need to do a case analysis. You need to check if either argument are not a list and return `#f` there, then if it's not you need to get the lengths of the two lists to check if they are of equal length or if the one list is maller than the other. Something like this perhaps?

```scm
(define (longest lst1 lst2)
  (if <??> ; check if one of the argument is not a list
      #f   
      (let ((len1 <??>) (len2 <??>))
        (cond ((= <??> <??>) #t)   ; same length
              ((< <??> <??>) <??>) ; lst1 shorter than lst2
              (else <??>>)))))     ; lst2 shorter than lst1
```

It seems like an assignment so I let you fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (longer-list a b)
  (and (list? a)
       (list? b)
       (let ll ((aa a) (bb b))
         (cond
           ((and (null? aa) (null? bb)) #t)
           ((null? aa) b)
           ((null? bb) a)
           (else (ll (cdr aa) (cdr bb)))))))
```